# Merging two Data Frames with no common unique column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, data-manipulation

I have two Data Frame. I wanna merge them but I don't find any common column in between.

`df1`

```
Date           var1   var2    var3   var4 
2022/01/01     10     100     110    50
2022/01/02     11     110     100    65
```

`df2`

```
 IDV_Key   IDV_Name
  var1     Variable 1
  var2     Variable 2
  var3     Variable 3
  var4     Variable 4
```

Desired output Data Frame would be:

`df`

```
Date           IDV       Value    IDV_Key    IDV_Name
2022/01/01     var1       10       var1      Variable 1
2022/01/01     var2       100      var2      Variable 2
2022/01/01     var3       110      var3      Variable 3
2022/01/01     var4       50       var4      Variable 4
2022/02/01     var1       11       var1      Variable 1
2022/02/01     var2       110      var2      Variable 2 
2022/02/01     var3       100      var3      Variable 3 
2022/02/01     var4       65       var4      Variable 4
```

Having issue since doesn't have any common unique columns on top of I can merge it.

I tried below commands:

```
df1 = df1.stack.reset_index(drop = True, inplace = True)  
df1.columns = [IDV, Value]   
df1['IDV_Name'] = df2['IDV_Name']  
df1
```

Comment: I see common `IDV` column, do you try merge?

Comment: You need explain why merge not working.

Comment: What is the output of `df1.merge(df2, on='IDV')`? If nothing, please **provide the full constructors for both datasets**. First ensure that there are no spaces or else that make it look identical even if they are in fact different

Comment: so need `df = df1.merge(df2, left_on='IDV', right_on='IDV_Key', how='left')` ?

Comment: check `melt` or `stack` in added dupe.

Comment: @mozway Please check now

Comment: @Amit "It doesn't work" or "it doesn't solve the problem" is not a valid reason. You need to **provide the explicit command** that you tried, and **describe how it doesn't meet your expectations**

Comment: @mozway I tried this
`df1 = df1.stack.reset_index(drop = True, inplace = True)
 df1.columns = [IDV, Value] 
 df1['IDV_Name'] = df2['IDV_Name']
 df1`

Comment: As mentioned above, edit the question with those details, provide the inputs as dataframe constructors, provide the error or details on the unwanted behavior